# How to modify part of header value in a http request with Charles Proxy rewrite tool and regex?

Tags: regex, http, charles-proxy

I'm trying to modify part of header value in a http request with Charles Proxy using rewrite tool / regex?

So the original header value might look at this

```
foolheader XXXXEFGH
```

I'm interested in changing the part `EFGH` and maintain anything before this, which is `XXXX`, so it could change into something like

```
foolheader XXXXIJKL
```

[image]

So is it possible to do it with regex? Thanks.

Comment: Why not replace `EFGH` with `IJKL`? Well, in a more general case, try `(foolheader .*?)EFGH` and replace with `$1IJKL`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. So for the match value I should use (.*?)EFGH ?

Comment: Yes, and for the Replace value, `$1IJKL`